# How to switch to an older version of rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to follow an older book written in 2011.

So, randomly picked [3.1.3](http://rubygems.org/gems/rails/versions/3.1.3) version since that's Nov 2011.

How do I switch to that version in my RVM?

Currently have `Rails 4.0.0.beta1` version ...

Please don't suggest to put it in the Gemfile because there are a lot of other dependencies that will just be too troublesome to deal with, hence if I just switch, I'm assuming it means that other dependencies will be taken care of at the same time too, right?

**UPDATE**

```
**-s-MacBook-Pro:agile **$ rails -v
Rails 4.0.0.beta1
**-s-MacBook-Pro:agile **$ gem install rails -v 3.1.3
Successfully installed rails-3.1.3
1 gem installed
**-s-MacBook-Pro:agile **$ rvm gemset create rails 313
gemset created rails    => /Users/**/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails
gemset created 313  => /Users/**/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@313
**-s-MacBook-Pro:agile **$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]
**-s-MacBook-Pro:agile **$ rvm 1.9.3p392-head@rails313
Unknown ruby interpreter version: '1.9.3p392'.
**-s-MacBook-Pro:agile **$
```

**UPDATE AGAIN**

```
**-s-MacBook-Pro:agile **$ rvm gemset use 313
Using ruby-1.9.3-p392 with gemset 313
**-s-MacBook-Pro:agile **$ rails -v
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in `to_specs': Could not find 'rails'     (>= 0) among 2 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:307:in `to_spec'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
from /usr/bin/rails:18
**-s-MacBook-Pro:agile **$
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

First, uninstall the version of Rails you have:

`gem uninstall rails`

Next, install the version of Rails you want, like so:

`gem install rails -v 3.1.12`

There are a few ways to have both "installed" at the same time. As Joe Frambach suggested, you could install Rails 4 in a VM. You could also install [RVM](http://rvm.io) - the Ruby enVironment Manager - and use separate gemsets to keep the two versions of Rails apart. But if you are just learning you may not want to bother with this.

**Edit:** @Shadwell's answer got it right, although it could use some expansion, which I'll do here:

```
> rvm gemset create rails3
> rvm gemset use rails3
> gem install rails -v 3.1.12
> rails my_new_app
```

Comment: If you have rvm, no need to uninstall, just use a gemset:  https://rvm.io/gemsets/basics/

Comment: @DGM, based on your link, first I do, 'gem install rails -v 3.1.3', and then did 'rvm gemset create rails 313', and then 'rvm 1.9.3p392-head@rails313' but I get this 'Unknown ruby interpreter version: '1.9.3p392'.'

Comment: @RyanWilcox, but I do have an RVM ... and hence trying to figure out that way. (sorry, hit enter on my earlier comment too soon)

Comment: ok, I've updated my answer to bridge the gap between my answer and Shadwell's answer. Hope this helps!

Comment: @RyanWilcox, your update helped to get the ball rolling with your edited answer. Thanks!

Comment: should be rvm gemset use rails3 - missing "s" in rails3

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I was stuck in a loop trying to update Ruby and realized I could just stick with installing older versions of gems with this (+1).

Answer (score 17):

I accidentally installed rails version `4.1.7` but I need rails version `4.1.6` . In order to fix this issue I uninstalled rails with this command:

`gem uninstall rails`

and install version 4.1.6 with:

`gem install rails -v 4.1.6`

but when I run `rails -v` it's version still be `4.1.7`.

By running `gem list` I see that `railties (4.1.7, 4.1.6)` package exist in my gems. I removed it with below procedure and fix rails version problem.

```
$ gem uninstall railties

Select gem to uninstall:
 1. railties-4.1.6
 2. railties-4.1.7
 3. All versions
>
```

Input 2 and uninstall version `4.1.7`.

Answer (score 6):

You're already using RVM it seems. Create a gemset for the different rails versions:

```
> rvm gemset create rails3
> rvm gemset use rails3
> bundle install
```

You'll then only get the gems installed in that gemset. I'd be tempted to create a gemset for rails4 too rather than having gems kicking around that aren't in a gemset. Then to switch between them you just `rvm gemset use` whichever one you want to.

There's more about gemset [here](https://rvm.io/gemsets/) and it'd be worth reading up on [rvmrc](https://rvm.io/workflow/rvmrc/) too because then you don't even have to switch gemsets.

Comment: I'm a little confused on the usage of gemsets ... this is what I get when I do 'rvm getset use 313' (will be pasting it in my post above)

Comment: Looks like you've installed rails then created the gemset. Once you've created the gemset you need to install rails into that gemset. You can always list the installed gems in the usual way with `gem list` which will show you those accessible to your gemset.

Comment: how to I install it into the gemset? Sorry, right now, everything is bit of a blur when I try to read the directions on RVM's site ...

Comment: Without this turning into an rvm tutorial (there are better ones out there), once you "use" the gemset then you're working within that gemset. So any gem operations you do, and bundler operations, will be working with the current gemset.

Comment: Hey, @Shadwell, thanks for your answer ... it did help me to get started.

Comment: shouldn't rail3 be rails3?

Answer (score 2):

We can change our default version of rails.
Rails version defined in Ruby "bin" itself.

install  required rails version by

```
gem install rails -v 4.2.6
```

and

#### In Windows:

- goto your current ruby version 'bin' folder ( in my system *c:/RubyXX-x64/bin*)
- you will find "rails" file there
- open that "rails" file with text editor
  you will see ----- **version = ">= 0"**
  (which means: it opens the highest version of rails, which exist in your ruby gems)
- replace it with specific rails version as ----- *version = "4.2.6"*

#### In Linux:

- goto ruby lib folder (in my system ---/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin)

> $ which bundle

(gives path to find from which ruby your bundler executing( ---/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/bundler) )

- edit "rails" file with your text editor

> dathu@ubuntu:~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin$ **sudo subl rails**

- replace ( verion = ">= 0" ) with ( verion = "4.2.6" ) your specific installed version.
- save and check your current rails version.