# How to downgrade Ruby and Rails versions without using RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using **Ruby 1.9.3p2** and **Rails 4.0** versions on my Linux machine.
Recently we got an maintenance project which is on versions **Ruby 1.8.7** and **Rails 2.3.2**. 
I tried of installing rvm, after that it asked to install ree. But it goes on continuously increasing packages to install.

Please tell me if there is any way without using rvm.

Comment: Checkout rbenv instead of rvm. You really don't want to be managing ruby versions manually.

Comment: Make a new vm on your machine, and install the version you want there.  Look into vagrant + virtual box.

Comment: Why don't you ask a question about the problems you're having with RVM? (But I think the question you asked here is also valid.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to switch to an older version of rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17052629/how-to-switch-to-an-older-version-of-rails)

Comment: The question in my previous comment might help you. It has an answer that shows how to change Rails versions without RVM. If you need to be able to use both versions of Rails for two projects you're maintaining simultaneously, though, it still might not help. Does that post answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

Using a version manager is the best way. If you don't want to use rvm, you could try using [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv), although I prefer rvm.