# Rails Not working for new project. ShowingError " superclass mismatch for class Cipher (TypeError)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My Rails and ruby are currently updated

```
rails -v
```

=> Rails 5.0.1

ruby -v

=>ruby 2.4.0p0 (2016-12-24 revision 57164) [x86_64-linux]

Created a new rails app

rails new myapp

cd myapp

(Enters to the project directory)

rails s

```
        /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::VERSION
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OPENSSL_LIBRARY_VERSION
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OPENSSL_FIPS
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Config::DEFAULT_CONFIG_FILE
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::PKCS7::Signer
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::PKCS7::TEXT
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::PKCS7::NOCERTS

    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_FLAG_EXTENDED_CRL_SUPPORT
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_FLAG_USE_DELTAS
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_FLAG_CHECK_SS_SIGNATURE
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_FLAG_NO_ALT_CHAINS
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::PURPOSE_SSL_CLIENT
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::PURPOSE_SSL_SERVER
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::PURPOSE_NS_SSL_SERVER
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::PURPOSE_SMIME_SIGN
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::PURPOSE_SMIME_ENCRYPT
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::PURPOSE_CRL_SIGN
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::PURPOSE_ANY
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::PURPOSE_OCSP_HELPER
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::PURPOSE_TIMESTAMP_SIGN
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::TRUST_COMPAT
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::TRUST_SSL_CLIENT
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::TRUST_SSL_SERVER
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::TRUST_EMAIL
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::TRUST_OBJECT_SIGN
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::TRUST_OCSP_SIGN
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::TRUST_OCSP_REQUEST
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::TRUST_TSA
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::DEFAULT_CERT_AREA
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::DEFAULT_CERT_DIR
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::DEFAULT_CERT_FILE
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::DEFAULT_CERT_DIR_ENV
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::DEFAULT_CERT_FILE_ENV
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::DEFAULT_PRIVATE_DIR
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::RESPONSE_STATUS_INTERNALERROR
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::RESPONSE_STATUS_MALFORMEDREQUEST
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::REVOKED_STATUS_NOSTATUS
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::RESPONSE_STATUS_SIGREQUIRED
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::RESPONSE_STATUS_SUCCESSFUL
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::RESPONSE_STATUS_TRYLATER
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::REVOKED_STATUS_AFFILIATIONCHANGED
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::REVOKED_STATUS_CACOMPROMISE
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::REVOKED_STATUS_CERTIFICATEHOLD
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::REVOKED_STATUS_CESSATIONOFOPERATION
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::REVOKED_STATUS_KEYCOMPROMISE
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::REVOKED_STATUS_REMOVEFROMCRL
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::REVOKED_STATUS_SUPERSEDED
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::RESPONSE_STATUS_UNAUTHORIZED
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::REVOKED_STATUS_UNSPECIFIED
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::NOCERTS
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::NOINTERN
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::NOSIGS
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::NOCHAIN
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::NOVERIFY
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::NOEXPLICIT
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::NOCASIGN
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::NODELEGATED
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::NOCHECKS
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::TRUSTOTHER
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::RESPID_KEY
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::NOTIME
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::V_CERTSTATUS_GOOD
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::V_CERTSTATUS_REVOKED
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::V_CERTSTATUS_UNKNOWN
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::V_RESPID_NAME
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::V_RESPID_KEY
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Engine::METHOD_RSA
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Engine::METHOD_DSA
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Engine::METHOD_DH
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Engine::METHOD_RAND
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Engine::METHOD_CIPHERS
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Engine::METHOD_DIGESTS
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Engine::METHOD_ALL
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Engine::METHOD_NONE
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::UNIVERSAL_TAG_NAME
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::EOC
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::BOOLEAN
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::INTEGER
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::BIT_STRING
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::OCTET_STRING
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::NULL
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::OBJECT
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::OBJECT_DESCRIPTOR
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::EXTERNAL
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::REAL
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::ENUMERATED
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::EMBEDDED_PDV
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::UTF8STRING
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::RELATIVE_OID
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::SEQUENCE
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::SET
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::NUMERICSTRING
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::PRINTABLESTRING
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::T61STRING
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::VIDEOTEXSTRING
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::IA5STRING
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::UTCTIME
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::GENERALIZEDTIME
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::GRAPHICSTRING
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::ISO64STRING
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::GENERALSTRING
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::UNIVERSALSTRING
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::CHARACTER_STRING
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::BMPSTRING
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/pkey.rb:8: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::PKey::DH::DEFAULT_1024
    /home/basil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/openssl-2.0.3/lib/openssl/pkey.rb:8: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT_1024 was here
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/pkey.rb:17: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::PKey::DH::DEFAULT_2048
    /home/basil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/openssl-2.0.3/lib/openssl/pkey.rb:17: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT_2048 was here
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/pkey.rb:30: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::PKey::DEFAULT_TMP_DH_CALLBACK
    /home/basil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/openssl-2.0.3/lib/openssl/pkey.rb:30: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT_TMP_DH_CALLBACK was here
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:18: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::AES
    /home/basil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/openssl-2.0.3/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: previous definition of AES was here
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:18: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::CAST5
    /home/basil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/openssl-2.0.3/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: previous definition of CAST5 was here
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:18: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::BF
    /home/basil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/openssl-2.0.3/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: previous definition of BF was here
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:18: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::DES
    /home/basil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/openssl-2.0.3/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: previous definition of DES was here
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:18: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::IDEA
    /home/basil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/openssl-2.0.3/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: previous definition of IDEA was here
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:18: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::RC2
    /home/basil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/openssl-2.0.3/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: previous definition of RC2 was here
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:18: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::RC4
    /home/basil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/openssl-2.0.3/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: previous definition of RC4 was here
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:18: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::RC5
    /home/basil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/openssl-2.0.3/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: previous definition of RC5 was here
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:28: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:33: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::AES128
    /home/basil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/openssl-2.0.3/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:33: warning: previous definition of AES128 was here
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:28: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:33: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::AES192
    /home/basil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/openssl-2.0.3/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:33: warning: previous definition of AES192 was here
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:28: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:33: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::AES256
    /home/basil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/openssl-2.0.3/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:33: warning: previous definition of AES256 was here
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:64: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:64: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
    /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:64:in `<class:Cipher>': superclass mismatch for class Cipher (TypeError)
        from /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:16:in `<module:OpenSSL>'
        from /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.rb:17:in `require'
        from /home/basil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/basil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/key_generator.rb:2:in `require'
        from /home/basil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/key_generator.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/basil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:4:in `require'
        from /home/basil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/basil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails.rb:11:in `require'
        from /home/basil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/basil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:4:in `require'
        from /home/basil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/basil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:138:in `require'
        from /home/basil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:138:in `require_command!'
        from /home/basil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:83:in `server'
        from /home/basil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
        from /home/basil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/basil/Desktop/b/myapp/bin/rails:9:in `require'
        from /home/basil/Desktop/b/myapp/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/basil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
        from /home/basil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
        from /home/basil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
        from /home/basil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
        from /home/basil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-2.0.1/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/basil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
        from /home/basil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/basil/Desktop/b/myapp/bin/spring:15:in `require'
        from /home/basil/Desktop/b/myapp/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:3:in `load'
        from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

And the project will display this error, dont even start!!

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 versions of openssl ( 2.0.2 and 2.0.3 ) which are loaded at the same time. Try reverting to default one 2.0.2 :

```
gem uninstall openssl -v 2.0.3

gem install openssl -v 2.0.2
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your RVM is using ruby-2.2.1 and you need to install 2.4.0

```
rvm install ruby-2.4.0
rvm default ruby-2.4.0
```

you can find all ruby version which are installed in your local machine using this command

```
rvm list
```

I suggest you to install it and retry again and I see your rbenv is using 2.4.0 and you rvm is using 2.2.1.

Comment: It worked for me for the new projects. But do I have to do this for the every time when I create  a project, is there a permanent way to to make it default

Comment: you don't need to do all the time because you already set your default version to `ruby 2.4.0`.

Comment: Ok, but after I upgraded to rails 5 , my old projects are not working, my old projects are showing the same error shown above. Do you have any document or info to solve this rails old version problem  ??

Comment: you need to create a gemset to use particular versions of rails. This thread might help you Click [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17052629/how-to-switch-to-an-older-version-of-rails)