# How to initialize rails 5.1 environment from ruby script for clockwork

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, clockwork

I need to initialise rails from an arbitrary script so that I can access some ActiveRecord objects using [Clockwork](https://github.com/Rykian/clockwork#example-clockrb-file)

UPDATE: The issue only occurs when `require 'clockwork'` and `require_relative './config/environment'` are both required.

They recommend initializing it like this:

```
# rails-root-directory/my-file.rb
require 'clockwork'
require_relative './config/boot'
require_relative './config/environment'
```

Sadly `require_relative './config/environment'` seems to be including `openssl` twice or something, resulting in a whole bunch of warnings and finally an error (below)

I'm running rails 5.1, ruby 4.2.1 using `rbenv` on MacOS High Sierra.

Not sure if this is the right way to initialize rails (googling seems to say it is) or if it's just an issue with my setup. Please help!

```
/Users/james/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:18: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
/Users/james/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::AES
/Users/james/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/openssl-2.0.5/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: previous definition of AES was here
/Users/james/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:18: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
/Users/james/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::CAST5
/Users/james/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/openssl-2.0.5/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: previous definition of CAST5 was here
/Users/james/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:18: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
/Users/james/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::BF
/Users/james/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/openssl-2.0.5/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: previous definition of BF was here
/Users/james/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:18: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
/Users/james/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::DES
/Users/james/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/openssl-2.0.5/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: previous definition of DES was here
/Users/james/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:18: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
/Users/james/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::IDEA
/Users/james/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/openssl-2.0.5/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: previous definition of IDEA was here
/Users/james/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:18: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
/Users/james/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::RC2
/Users/james/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/openssl-2.0.5/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: previous definition of RC2 was here
/Users/james/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:18: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
/Users/james/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::RC4
/Users/james/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/openssl-2.0.5/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: previous definition of RC4 was here
/Users/james/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:18: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
/Users/james/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::RC5
/Users/james/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/openssl-2.0.5/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: previous definition of RC5 was here
/Users/james/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:28: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
/Users/james/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:33: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::AES128
/Users/james/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/openssl-2.0.5/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:33: warning: previous definition of AES128 was here
/Users/james/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:28: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
/Users/james/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:33: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::AES192
/Users/james/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/openssl-2.0.5/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:33: warning: previous definition of AES192 was here
/Users/james/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:28: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
/Users/james/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:33: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::AES256
/Users/james/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/openssl-2.0.5/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:33: warning: previous definition of AES256 was here
/Users/james/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:64: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
/Users/james/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:64: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
/Users/james/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:64:in `<class:Cipher>': superclass mismatch for class Cipher (TypeError)
    from /Users/james/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:16:in `<module:OpenSSL>'
    from /Users/james/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/james/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.rb:17:in `require'
    from /Users/james/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/james/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/key_generator.rb:2:in `require'
    from /Users/james/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/key_generator.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/james/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:4:in `require'
    from /Users/james/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/james/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails.rb:12:in `require'
    from /Users/james/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/james/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/all.rb:1:in `require'
    from /Users/james/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/all.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/james/sites/mergefreezev2/config/application.rb:3:in `require'
    from /Users/james/sites/mergefreezev2/config/application.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/james/sites/mergefreezev2/config/environment.rb:2:in `require_relative'
    from /Users/james/sites/mergefreezev2/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from clock.rb:4:in `require_relative'
    from clock.rb:4:in `<main>'
```

Gemfile (aside from rails 5.1 default gems)

```
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-github'
gem 'httparty'
gem 'resque'
gem 'resque-web', require: 'resque_web'
gem 'chronic'
gem 'tzinfo'
gem 'clockwork'
gem 'geoip'
```

Local Gem List:

```
$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actioncable (5.1.4, 5.1.3)
actionmailer (5.1.4, 5.1.3)
actionpack (5.1.4, 5.1.3)
actionview (5.1.4, 5.1.3)
activejob (5.1.4, 5.1.3)
activemodel (5.1.4, 5.1.3)
activerecord (5.1.4, 5.1.3)
activesupport (5.1.4, 5.1.3)
addressable (2.5.2)
arel (8.0.0)
bcrypt (3.1.11)
bigdecimal (default: 1.3.0)
bindex (0.5.0)
builder (3.2.3)
bundler (1.16.1, 1.15.4)
byebug (9.1.0)
capybara (2.17.0, 2.16.1, 2.15.1)
childprocess (0.8.0, 0.7.1)
chronic (0.10.2)
clockwork (2.0.2)
coderay (1.1.2)
coffee-rails (4.2.2)
coffee-script (2.4.1)
coffee-script-source (1.12.2)
commonjs (0.2.7)
concurrent-ruby (1.0.5)
crass (1.0.3)
devise (4.3.0)
did_you_mean (1.1.0)
domain_name (0.5.20170404)
erubi (1.7.0, 1.6.1)
et-orbi (1.0.8)
execjs (2.7.0)
faraday (0.13.1, 0.12.2)
ffi (1.9.18)
font-awesome-sass (4.7.0)
geoip (1.6.3)
globalid (0.4.1, 0.4.0)
hashie (3.5.7, 3.5.6)
http-cookie (1.0.3)
httparty (0.15.6)
i18n (0.9.1, 0.8.6)
io-console (default: 0.4.6)
jbuilder (2.7.0)
jquery-rails (4.3.1)
json (default: 2.0.2)
jwt (1.5.6)
less (2.6.0)
less-rails (2.8.0)
listen (3.1.5)
loofah (2.1.1, 2.0.3)
mail (2.7.0, 2.6.6)
mailgun_rails (0.9.0)
method_source (0.9.0, 0.8.2)
mime-types (3.1)
mime-types-data (3.2016.0521)
mini_mime (1.0.0, 0.1.4)
mini_portile2 (2.3.0, 2.2.0)
minitest (5.11.1)
mono_logger (1.1.0)
multi_json (1.12.2, 1.12.1)
multi_xml (0.6.0)
multipart-post (2.0.0)
mustermann (1.0.1)
mysql2 (0.4.10, 0.4.9)
net-telnet (0.1.1)
netrc (0.11.0)
nio4r (2.2.0, 2.1.0)
nokogiri (1.8.1, 1.8.0)
oauth2 (1.4.0)
octokit (4.7.0)
omniauth (1.8.1, 1.6.1)
omniauth-github (1.3.0, 1.1.2)
omniauth-google-oauth2 (0.5.2)
omniauth-oauth2 (1.5.0, 1.4.0, 1.3.1)
omniauth-slack (2.3.0)
openssl (2.0.5, default: 2.0.3)
orm_adapter (0.5.0)
power_assert (0.4.1)
pry (0.11.3, 0.10.4)
psych (default: 2.2.2)
public_suffix (3.0.1, 3.0.0)
puma (3.11.0, 3.10.0)
rack (2.0.3)
rack-protection (2.0.0)
rack-test (0.8.2, 0.7.0, 0.6.3)
rails (5.1.4, 5.1.3)
rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
railties (5.1.4, 5.1.3)
rake (12.3.0, 12.0.0)
rb-fsevent (0.10.2)
rb-inotify (0.9.10)
rdoc (default: 5.0.0)
redis (4.0.1)
redis-namespace (1.6.0)
responders (2.4.0)
resque (1.27.4)
resque-scheduler (4.3.1)
resque-scheduler-web (1.1.0)
resque-web (0.0.12)
rest-client (2.0.2)
ruby_dep (1.5.0)
rubyzip (1.2.1)
rufus-scheduler (3.4.2)
sass (3.5.5, 3.5.4, 3.5.3, 3.5.1)
sass-listen (4.0.0)
sass-rails (5.0.7, 5.0.6)
sawyer (0.8.1)
selenium-webdriver (3.8.0, 3.7.0, 3.5.2, 3.5.1)
sinatra (2.0.0)
slop (3.6.0)
spring (2.0.2)
spring-watcher-listen (2.0.1)
sprockets (3.7.1)
sprockets-rails (3.2.1)
sqlite3 (1.3.13)
test-unit (3.2.3)
thor (0.20.0)
thread_safe (0.3.6)
tilt (2.0.8)
turbolinks (5.0.1)
turbolinks-source (5.0.3)
twitter-bootstrap-rails (4.0.0)
tzinfo (1.2.4, 1.2.3)
tzinfo-data (1.2017.3)
uglifier (4.1.2, 4.1.0, 3.2.0)
unf (0.1.4)
unf_ext (0.0.7.4)
vegas (0.1.11)
warden (1.2.7)
web-console (3.5.1)
websocket-driver (0.6.5)
websocket-extensions (0.1.3, 0.1.2)
xmlrpc (0.2.1)
xpath (3.0.0, 2.1.0)
```

Comment: Unable to replicate your problem, this is a case where the same class is being again defined by code from some other gem or some place in your own code. Could you share the `Gemfile`, so I can eliminate one of the above possibilties ? Only the list of gems that do not come with the Rails 5.1 setup would be enough.

Comment: You could look into 'rails runner' command.

Comment: @bitsapien thanks for taking a look. Have updated the question with Gemfile. I also realized that the issue only occurs when `require 'clockwork'` is also inserted at the top of the file.

Comment: @sethi I think it has to be able to run by itself in order for it to be run by the [clockwork](https://github.com/Rykian/clockwork) executable

Comment: If you open a Rails project, call irb and execute `"require_relative 'config/environment.rb'"` the Rails app is loaded - what happens if you try without 'config/boot' line?

Comment: @Mat yep I tried removing the `config/boot` line. Unfortunately same problem. Try installing `clockwork` gem then in irb executing `require 'clockwork'` then `require_relative 'config/environment.rb'`. I get errors.

Comment: @JamesPlayer the problem could be somewhere else, openssl related, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42070978/rails-not-working-for-new-project-showingerror-superclass-mismatch-for-class) for example

Comment: @Mat thank you that was it! Fixed with `gem uninstall openssl -v 2.0.5` then `gem install openssl -v 2.0.3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was that I had two versions of the `openssl` gem trying to be loaded at the same time.

doing a `gem list` showed: `openssl (2.0.5, default: 2.0.3)`

Reverting to the default version fixed the problem:

```
gem uninstall openssl -v 2.0.5
gem install openssl -v 2.0.3
```