# Adding Factory Bot To Rails Test Suite Breaks It

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rubygems, factory-bot

**EDIT: This problem has been solved. [The thread that solved my problem can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42070978/rails-not-working-for-new-project-showingerror-superclass-mismatch-for-class). Thanks to @mrzasa for pointing this out.**

As soon as I set up Factory Bot in this project and run the `rspec spec` command, my test suite fails. But it was running perfectly fine before that.

I've set up Factory Bot before. I know what I'm doing in this regard. This isn't a question about config or initialisation.

More background info:

Here are the gems of interest for :test, :dev environments:

```
factory_bot 5.1.0, 5.0.2
factory_bot_rails 5.1.0, 5.0.2
rspec-support 3.8.2
rspec-rails 3.8.2
rspec-mocks 3.8.1
rspec-core 3.8.2
rspec-expecrtations 3.8.4
rspec-activemodel-mocks 1.1.0
```

Now the error messages:

When I specify Factory_Bot v. 5.1.0 & Factory_Bot_rails v. 5.1.0

```
TypeError: Superclass mismatch for class Cipher 
/Users/richardjarram/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:64
constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
```

**EDIT: I removed duplicate open_ssl versions in the gemset. RSpec is now working again. [Thread that solved my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42070978/rails-not-working-for-new-project-showingerror-superclass-mismatch-for-class) and thanks to @mrzasa for pointing this out.**

When I specify Factory_Bot v 5.0.2 & Factory_Bot_Rails v.5.0.2

```
/Users/richardjarram/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.8.2/lib
/rspec/core/reporter.rb:229:in `require': cannot load such file -- rspec/core/profiler (LoadError)
```

I actually dug into the core rspec files in my gems and I've noticed that on l.229 the Profile.new class is being called but there is no require in the file. This entire situation is incredibly bizarre.

**EDIT: Once the open_ssl issue was solved, FactoryBot is working on the latest version (5.1.0). The older version (5.0.2) however, is imcompatible with my current project.**

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails Not working for new project. ShowingError " superclass mismatch for class Cipher (TypeError)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42070978/rails-not-working-for-new-project-showingerror-superclass-mismatch-for-class)

Comment: Do you need both `factory_bot` and `factory_bot_rails`?