# How to use lower version of rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

I am working on a project that requires Rails 2.3.3. I have Rails 5.2.2 already installed in my system.

I am asking how to install Rails 2.3.3 and work on that project. Any links would be much appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17052629/how-to-switch-to-an-older-version-of-rails/17052754

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to switch to an older version of rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17052629/how-to-switch-to-an-older-version-of-rails)

Comment: Read about gemsets if you use rvm

Comment: Please specify more information about your project. Are you using bundler for installing gems? Do you have a Gemfile for us? Are you using RVM or RBENV to switch between different ruby versions per project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use rvm for different rails applications.

Try this link https://rvm.io/rvm/install.

After installing rvm.  in your gem file you can mention your rails version. it will install automatically.

gem 'rails', '~> 2.3.3'